# ReferenceError: printStackTrace is not defined

Tags: angularjs, stacktrace.js

I get the following error "ReferenceError: printStackTrace is not defined",
when I tried to use StackTrace in my angular aplication.

Comment: please provide code and logs

Comment: I should use `StackTrace.fromError(error).then(callback).catch(errback);`
and not `printStackTrace({e: error})`.
`printStackTrace()` is for the old versions v0.x:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

stacktrace.js changed the API for v1.0.

You'll want to use

```
var callback = function(frames) { console.log(frames); };
var errback = function(err) { console.log(err.message); };

StackTrace.get().then(callback).catch(errback);
```

as suggested by [the docs](http://www.stacktracejs.com/#!/docs/stacktrace-js).

If all you want to do is parse an `Error` you can just use [error-stack-parser](https://github.com/stacktracejs/error-stack-parser)

Please refer to the [v0.x -> v1.x migration guide](http://www.stacktracejs.com/#!/docs/v0-migration-guide) if you were using the old version.

By the way, if you need to use version 0.x you can find it in [the stable branch](https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js/tree/stable) on GitHub